# Jquery & prototype conflict on api menu, colorbox

Tags: jquery

I'm tryin to use a color box & api query on my website below. But this stops the recommended, reccentely listened, tabs from loading.. If I remove the header menu it works fine. I tried searching for no conflict method but doesnt seem to be working. Can you please help  me with this.. spent hours searching and applying various techniques but to no avail :(

http://songspal.com/hindi/music/index.html

The top menu has options like radio & videos which open in colorbox. This is preventing the other content from loading in the Music module, top charts, activities, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a solution without seeing code, but one method for getting around prototype / jquery conflicts (they both use '$') is via a closure:

```
(function($){
    $('#someDiv').somePlugin({someArgument:someValue});
    //do more jquery stuff using '$';
})(jQuery);
```

You can also overcome this by switching out '$' for 'jQuery' in your code.

Comment: thanks for the response.. code here.. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://songspal.com/menu/menu.js"></script>
 <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://songspal.com/colorbox.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://songspal.com/menu/jquery.colorbox.js"></script><link type="text/css" href="http://songspal.com/menu/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Also I tried the above method.. doesnt seem to be working.. will be glad if you could give an example based on the code.. thanks again..